# Scroll to element IDs in mobile

Tags: jquery, skrollr

I am having issue with using skrollr on mobile. I have attached

```
id="skrollr-body"
```

to the html element (white screen and other odd behaviour if I attach it to body), which allows my responsive site to be scrolled. I have attached

```
s.refresh();
```

to any js function which changes an elements height so page height is always correctly figured out. This all seems to work nicely except I have two functions that should scroll to elements via their ID.

```
jQuery(".scrolldown").click(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#article-bottom").offset().top
    }, 800);
});

jQuery(".scrollup").click(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#article-top").offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

These functions work nicely in desktop version but struggle in mobile (particularly going up to the top of the page). The scrolldown kind of works, in that the page will scroll down - but I notice that no transformations are occurring on the html element.

This means once I scroll down, I cannot scroll back up as the transformation is still at 0,0. I tried

```
jQuery(".scrolldown").click(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#article-bottom").offset().top
    }, 800);
    s.refresh();
});
```

adding `s.refresh()` after (and before) the animation but I am stumped. I think these functions should be using transforms in mobile (like the main page) but I don't know if I am writing these functions correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. Firstly, I read the documentation. Secondly, I included `skrollr.menu.min.js` and added the code like this.

```
jQuery(".scrolldown").click(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#article-intro").offset().top
    }, 800);
});

var s = skrollr.init({forceHeight: false});

skrollr.menu.init(s, {
    animate: true,
    easing: 'sqrt',
    scale: 2,
    duration: function(currentTop, targetTop) {return 800;}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"These functions work nicely in desktop version but struggle in mobile (particularly going up to the top of the page)"

I'm not entirely sure what your question is asking specifically - but I believe what your talking about is the animation when scrolling around the page is choppy, or as you put it 'struggling'.

A general rule when working with mobile - CSS animations always win. This is because anything animated via CSS can take advantage of being hardware accelerated by the devices GPU. What this means is CSS animations look super smooth whereas the .animate() method is less reliable and often looks choppy.

While I don't have a code example to go with this - I do have a link which describes this in more detail and I believe it will put you in the right direction to fixing your "struggling" issues.

http://www.sitepoint.com/easily-improving-jquery-animations/

It talks about a nice JS lib called Velocity - https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity

Add this small script to your site and replace all instances of ".animate()" with ".velocity()" and it should solve your problem.

Like I said I'm not sure this answer is what you're after due to the wording of your question. Hope it helps though.